# add Meteor DocHead => DocHead.loadScript with Flow-router-ssr.

Tags: meteor

Can't figure out how to add the analytics code using **DocHead.loadScript** . Documentation assume that you more or less already understand it.

Have been trying in component, Client etc. Manage to get DocHead.setTitle(title); etc to work without problem.

**Where do i add this DocHead.loadScript to make it work?**

```
var gaScript = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
DocHead.loadScript(gaScript, function() {
    // Google Analytics loaded
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

Github: https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead

Comment: I'm struggling with something similar and I very much agree that the package readme assumes a lot of knowledge on the part of the reader.

Comment: @rubie Don't know if this help but did check the old code from this project and what i written then was:
componentWillUpdate: function() {
        DocHead.setTitle(this.data.video._id);
      },


      getDocHead() {
        if (Meteor.isServer) {
          DocHead.setTitle(this.data.video._id);
        
        }
      },

Comment: And basicly what author said when i was talking with him was to put the Google analytics code in a index.html file just.  It depends what setup you are using also.

Comment: Thanks @Mathias Asberg! I'm actually trying to get facebook/twitter meta tags working and it's difficult to tell whether the problem lies with my use of DocHead, spiderable, phantomjs, or something else...